# How can I use PHP code in a CSS file

Tags: php, css, sql, image, src

I want to find an image source from a MySQL database and assign it to a css style. I just changed the `.css` extension to `.php`.

It does work with XAMPP and runs everything I want, but when I uploaded my code in cpanel it didn't work correctly.

I used this code in the css file:

Top of page:

```
<?php include '../Connections/Base.php'; ?>
 <?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>
```

Some styles:

```
.box {
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
    border:4px solid #171717;
    position:absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    background:url(<?php 
        $query = "SELECT imape_path FROM MyTable WHERE number='5' LIMIT 1";
        //echo $query;
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $row['imape_path'];
            }
        }
 ?>) no-repeat;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You will need to change file type to .php and echo current css code inside that , though this method is not preferred.

Comment: if i change css codes to php echo , can HTML tags give data from php echo and convert it to css style?

Comment: Note that: my codes doing work with XAMPP but it have problem with CPanel

Comment: Could you plz post error if possible

Comment: It don't get any errors, just It don't set css style to HTML tags, Tables and divs in HTML will be tumultuous

Comment: when i use same codes with css extension it do work truly in CPanel, but can't load image path from SQL , and when I change it to php extension it don't load css style to HTML tags and can't load image path form Sql , too at CPanel

Comment: Did you really just put SQL access inside a css file? Worst idea of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I do not think this is the right problem to address.

The whole point in separating markup and styles is to simplify things. I see very little value in separating it so rigidly you have to mix css, php and sql instead (you just moved the same problem elsewhere).

My suggestion is to configure `.box`'s background using inline css in the html page itself and inject the url as any other value:

```
<div class="box" style="background: url('<?php ... ?>')">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping the .css extension on the file with PHP code, and setting a rule in .htaccess to parse the file as PHP ([source](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/)).

```
<FilesMatch "^.*?style.*?$">
SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```